# How to mention partial file name inside escape_javascript in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I was using the code in https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/ to implement a cascading dropdown.

It works like a charm

However, I would like to be able to mention the partial file name in my coffee script:

```
# app/views/welcome/update_cities.js.coffee

$("#cities_select").empty()
.append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @cities)) %>")
```

1. How do I do that?
       It tried doing this, but it did not work:

   ```
   $("#cities_select").empty()
   .append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "city", :object => @cities)) %>")
   ```

   What am I doing wrong here?
2. How does Rails know to call _city.html.erb? I don't understand the connection!

Please help!

Comment: "it did not work" .... in what way did it not work. Are there error messages, any stack trace, or does it simply not do what you expected?

Comment: I did not get any error messages. Both the drop-down were displayed, but when I changed the selection on the first drop-down, it did not trigger a change in the values in the second drop-down.

Comment: You're using double quotes for `"city"` and it's closing the global string. Try using single ones

Comment: I assume you have a change event handler for the first drop-down ... could you include the code for that in your question.

Comment: Check this guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials it explains how rails finds the name of the partial from the object class, how to render partials for a collection, etc.

Comment: @arieljuod, @kevcha, @david  - thank you all for your inputs:

I tried changing my code to this:

`$("#cities_select").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'cities/city', :object => @cities) %>")`

I get this error now (so it IS recognizing the partial, but there seems to be some other issue):

Comment: This is the error I get now:

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for #<City::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd32891c028>):
    1: <option value="<%= city.id %>"><%= city.name.titleize %></option>
  app/views/cities/_city.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_cities__city_html_erb___3449901543843616710_70272447967600'
  app/views/welcome/update_cities.js.coffee:2:in _app_views_welcome_update_cities_js_coffee___2988383591456931485_70272447776700'
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:14:in `update_cities'`

Comment: For some reason, rails is not able to recognize field "id" in model "city" but it was working fine earlier!! I don't understand how mentioning a partial name explicitly would make a field in a model unrecognizable

Comment: `make a field in a model unrecognizable`, the problem was that you passed a collection of object as 1 object, that's why `id` was undefined, check the error, it says `City::ActiveRecord_Relation`, that's like an array of objects, and it does not respond to `id`. When you pass `@cities` as the `:collection` options, it tells rails to use each element instead of the whole array-like object.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#cities_select").empty() .append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'cities/city', :collection => @cities) %>")
```

This worked fine for me! Thanks!